# How to implement multiple background image effect in IE8 +GWT

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gwt

I want multiple background image effect in IE 8 , Is it possible or is there any alternative way to apply on element.

Answer (score 1):

As IE8 supports `:pseudo elements` so using `:after` and `:before` you can create a Multiple background effect. Have a look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pahiruma/1/edit)**.

**HTML** 
*required just one div.*

```
<div id="silverback"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#silverback {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width:500px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/100/150/") no-repeat;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  zoom:1;
  border:1px solid #ef8913;
}
#silverback:before {
  height:150px;
  width:100px;
  content: " ";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:110px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x150/") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#silverback:after {
  height: 150px;
  width:100px;
  content: " ";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:220px;
 background: url("http://lorempixel.com/100/150/") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**As per comments posted a updated DEMO.**

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pahiruma/3/edit)**

Comment: .actionPanel {margin-top: 7px;margin-left: 5px;text-align: center;background:url("cloud/images/left_top_round.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;url("cloud/images/right_top_round.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 0px,url("cloud/images/left_bottom_round.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 100%,
      url("cloud/images/right_bottom_round.png") no-repeat 100% 100%,
url("cloud/images/left_middle.png") repeat-y scroll 0px 0px,
url("cloud/images/top_middle.png") repeat-x scroll 0px 0px,
url("cloud/images/right_middle.png") repeat-y scroll 100% 0px,
}  how i'll manage this..

Comment: no Actually I am confused because I have GWT element i.e VerticalPaneland How I'll apply on it?

Comment: great and then you may call specific classes.

Comment: let me guess; so for example if you are using `cloud background image` and those have 7 different images.

Answer (score 0):

Use overlapping DIVs and apply background images to them, IE8 does not support this CSS3 rule (http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds)

Comment: Can you just give me some example..  I have vertical panel in gwt and I want to apply multiple backgrounds to that panel.. how I 'll do ?

Answer (score 0):

We can apply a background-image to div using its css property "background", doing this we are done with 
one image.
Now to add another background-image to the div add a class to the div. set the class css
with another background image.

Example
we have a div inside which we have an anchor tag on which we want to apply two background-images

Now if we want to apply another background-image to this same anchor tag
try using

```
<div><div class="clsAnother"></div><a style="background:url()"></a></div>


In style tag, give style to this class:
class="clsAnother"></div><a {background:url(../../CustomerImages/tick-icon.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
```

This will add another image to the background of the anchor.
Note: You need to add class only in case of IE as IE does not understand multiple url in "background" property.
Although multiple url in "background" property works well with Mozilla and Chrome.